# Postgres files taking up lots of space

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have nearly 40G of files on my OSX, all under the following path :

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/base/9466989
36G    total
1.0G    10107638.6
1.0G    10107638.5
1.0G    10107638.4
1.0G    10107638.3
1.0G    10107638.2
1.0G    10107638.1
… 100x
```

I've done a `VACUUM FULL` on all the databases in there via psql, and yet they are still there.

Short of dropping everything and reimporting, how can I resolve this?

Comment: First thing to do is figure out what they are. Are you certain they're part of the currently running PostgreSQL you're using, not some different instance? Check which table they are. `select datname from pg_database where oid = 9466989` to get the database they are from. Then `select relname, nspname from pg_class c inner join pg_namespace n on (c.relnamespace = n.oid) where c.oid = 10107638` to get the table name.

Comment: The `datname` select returns 1 row, a known rails database (project_development). The `relname` select returns 0 rows, even when connected to that database. Thanks.